# plupload - issue with chunk size

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, plupload

I've just starting out using plupload and have tried the basic example and the PHP chunked example.

These seem to work fine when I keep my chunk_size to `2048kb`

However, if I increase this value the webpage shows the file has uploaded correctly but the upload folder either doesn't show the file or only a very small file. ( a few kb )

This is how I have plupload defined:

```
var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
    runtimes : 'html5,silverlight,html4',
    browse_button: 'browse',
    multi_selection: false,
    url: 'upload.php',
    chunk_size: '2048kb',
    max_retries: 3
});
```

My upload script is very simple using their example.

```
<?php

    if (empty($_FILES) || $_FILES['file']['error']) {
        die('{"OK": 0, "info": "Failed to move uploaded file."}');
    }

    $chunk = isset($_REQUEST["chunk"]) ? intval($_REQUEST["chunk"]) : 0;
    $chunks = isset($_REQUEST["chunks"]) ? intval($_REQUEST["chunks"]) : 0;

    $fileName = isset($_REQUEST["name"]) ? $_REQUEST["name"] : $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $filePath = "uploads/$fileName";


    // Open temp file
    $out = @fopen("{$filePath}.part", $chunk == 0 ? "wb" : "ab");
    if ($out) {
        // Read binary input stream and append it to temp file
        $in = @fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "rb");

        if ($in) {
            while ($buff = fread($in, 4096))
                fwrite($out, $buff);
        } else
            die('{"OK": 0, "info": "Failed to open input stream."}');

        @fclose($in);
        @fclose($out);

        @unlink($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
    } else
        die('{"OK": 0, "info": "Failed to open output stream."}');


    // Check if file has been uploaded
    if (!$chunks || $chunk == $chunks - 1) {
        // Strip the temp .part suffix off 
        rename("{$filePath}.part", $filePath);
    }

    die('{"OK": 1, "info": "Upload successful."}');
    ?>
```

I see no errors or warnings in the apache2 error_log, so I'm a bit stuck.

Any idea how I can increase the chunk size and have it work correctly?

Comment: I've got this working by adding a .htaccess file to my plupload folder and increasing the `php_value post_max_size 12M` & `php_value upload_max_filesize 12M` Values